# ¿Cómo implementar método de una interfaz en la clase padre para usarlo en el hijo?

Tags: python, poo, herencia, interface

**¡Hola!**

Actualmente estoy desarrollando una aplicación que trata de conectarse (vía ssh/telnet) a dispositivos de distintas marcas, principalmente Switches y APs. No obstante algunos problemillas en el desarrollo, en concreto con las herencias.

Cuando creo un dispositivo quiero que herede de ***Brand*** y ***Device***. Por ejemplo, si tengo un ***AP* de Cisco** quiero crear un objeto "AP_Cisco" que **herede de *AP* y Cisco**. Pero he aquí el problema: he hecho varias interfaces con el propósito de hacer una subclase, por ejemplo, una clase Cisco que hereda de **Brand** pero, cuando intento heredar de la marca implementada no quiero seguir implementándola en AP_Cisco porque he hecho el código en Cisco

Al mismo tiempo hay atributos en la clase hija (AP_Cisco) que hereda de **AP** y que requiero usarla en **Cisco**.

Tal vez el código haga esto más claro:

```py
class Brand(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def get_time(self) -> str:
       raise notImplementedError

class Cisco(Brand):

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def connection(self):
        ''' Returns the child connection '''


    # Inheritated from Brand
    def get_time(self) -> str :
        return self.execute('show clock')

class AP_Cisco(AP, Cisco):

    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection

    # Inheritated from Cisco --> I already implemented in Cisco
```

El problema es que cuando hago esto también recibo un error que me dice que necesito implementar en AP_Cisco `get_time()`.

> **TypeError:** Can't instantiate abstract class AP_Cisco with abstract methods get_time

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Una alternativa es composición; crear una clase nueva que contenga instancia de las clases necesarias (creadas o recibidas como parámetro) y coordine su interacción.

Comment: Ya está solucionado: era una problema de MRO ya que primero debía heredar de Cisco y luego de AP. ¡Muchas gracias de todas maneras!

Comment: La respuesta sería muy muy útil como respuesta, abajo, en el campo Tu Respuesta. Lo otro: la pregunta debió ir en español. Si te parece cool la idea de dejarle a otros en el futuro tu solución, te invito a editar la pregunta y formular tu respuesta con algo más de detalle :)

Comment: @EduardoJiménez la traducción de la pregunta debe hacerla el OP. Es por esto que dos usuarios [rechazaron tu edición](/review/suggested-edits/293237); el primero que la aprobó probablemente no sabe que no debía aprobar la edición.

Comment: @padaleiana gracias, tampoco sabía eso

Comment: Yo la verdad es que soy muy nuevo en esto de Stack OverFlow jeje. Ahora hago los cambios pertinentes. Creo que la traducción está bien.